# Is f(z) = z^n analytic on C, if n is rational

Tags: complex-analysis

My reasoning why it shouldn't be the case is as follows: 
Doing a general contour integration of f = z^n along a circle of radius 1 gives us i*int(cos(n+1)t,dt,0,2pi) - int(sin(t+1)t,dt,0,2pi) 
which is equal to $0$ if n is an integer

But if n isn't an integer, the contour integral would be non-zero, meaning, it isn't analytic (since integral around a closed loop is non-zero)

However, I feel like z^2.2 (for example) should be entire since we don't get any holes (i couldn't check the cauchy-reimann equations for z^2.2 since I don't know how to deal with the .2 power)

EDIT: the defintion of z^(1/n) is the principle value of z^(1/n) [so something that wolfram alpha would show you if you typed (2+2i)^(1/3) for example]

Comment: Kindly use Mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What is your *definition* of $z^n$ for rational $n$, e.g. $z^{1/3}$?

Comment: The definition is exactly what you would expect (if you typed it into wolfram alpha for example) .

So if you are given some z  = x +iy, 
Then z^(1/3) for example would just be (x+iy)^(1/3)

Comment: EDIT: To put it more mathematically, its the principle value of z^(n), when n is rational

Comment: Note that the principal value of a complex root is not even *continuous* in $\Bbb C$..

Comment: Let's say we were in a small domain (lets say |z| < 1) , would it be analytic on a small domain ? (instead of all of $C$)

Comment: It's not even continuous on any neighborhood of $0$ no matter how you cut it.

Comment: Ah so no matter how i define it, it just wouldn't work, so I shouldn't worry about the case when n is rational ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $q = a/b$ be a rational number. Then a reasonable interpretation for a function $f$ to be equal to $z \mapsto z^{1/b}$ would be a function which is a section of $z \mapsto z^b$, i.e. satisfies $f(z)^b = z$ for all $z$ in the domain of $f$.

Such a function may be constructed locally, via the Inverse Function Theorem. Observe that $z\mapsto z^b$ has nonzero derivative on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$. Thus, given any point $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ and number $w$ such that $w^b = z$, we can find such an $f: U \to \mathbb{C}$ with $f(z) = w$ for some open set $U$ containing $z$. If $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ is any simply connected domain containing $z$, then we can in fact extend our $f$ across $\Omega$ as well.

The problem is that no such $f$ can be globally defined, as you point out, as it cannot be analytically continued aroung the origin. Ensuring $\Omega$ is simply connected avoids such issues.

So, we can define a branch $f$ of $z \mapsto z^{1/b}$ on any simply connected subset $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$; then $z\mapsto f(z)^a$ gives a branch of $z \mapsto z^{a/b}$ on $\Omega$.